# Ionic 5 Firebase Realtime - Favorites in a list

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4, angularfire2

I have an Ionic 5 app with a list of motorcycles. In that, the user can favorite them, using a toggle star icon. Then, I  create a register in the user's node containing the motorcycle data, like this:

[image]

The problem is that I am not able to display the "star" icon in the list (always displays "star-outline") when the motorcycle was previously marked as "favorite" by the current user, although I can obtain this data from Firebase.

So far I have tried this way, unsuccessfully (the star icon keeps "star-outline" in all items):

list.page.html

```
<ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let item of motos; let i = index;">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-fab vertical="top" horizontal="start">
        <ion-fab-button (click)="addToFavorites(item, i)" icon-only color="clear">
          <ion-icon [name]="item.favourited ? 'star' : 'star-outline'"></ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>
      </ion-fab>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
        <div>{{item.fabricante}} {{item.nome}}</div>
        <div>{{item.ano_model}}</div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

list.page.ts

```
import { CrudMethodsService } from './services/crud-methods.service';

basePath = 'motos';
basePathU = 'users';

constructor(private crudServices: CrudMethodsService, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {      
 this.crudServices.getMotos(this.basePath).subscribe(res => {
    this.motos = res;
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user){
        this.userId = user.uid;
        const favoritas = 'favoritas';
        this.crudServices.getFavorites(this.basePathU, this.userId, favoritas).subscribe(us => {
          this.isFavorite = us;
          this.isFavorite.forEach(resp => {
            const item = this.motos;
            const p = this.favorites.indexOf(item);
            item.favourited = item.favourited ? false : true;
            for (let j = 0; j < this.motos.length; j++) {
              if (resp.item.key === this.motos[j].key && p === -1) {
                this.favorites.push(item);
                item.favourited = true;
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

crud-methods.service.ts

```
getMotos(basePath: string) {
  return this.db.list(basePath).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => {
      const data = c.payload.val();
      const id = c.payload.key;
      return { key: id, ...(data as object) };
    });
  }));
}

getFavorites(basePath: string, key: string, path: string) {
  return this.db.list(basePath + '/' + key + '/' + path).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => {
      const data = c.payload.val();
      const id = c.payload.key;
      return { key: id, ...(data as object) };
    });
  }));
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that you got the types right in your constructor. 
`this.motos` seems to be an array of moto objects `[{id ...},{id ...}]`. In the template you use it to display all motorcycles.

In the constructor there are two lines I'm not sure about what you want to acieve with:

    `const item = this.motos;
    const p = this.favorites.indexOf(item);`

Why should you look for an array of motorcycles in an array of motorcycles?

Comment: @DavidB. These lines are just a try to include the second get results (only favorite motorcycles by the current user) into the array of motorcycles (the first get). Obviously this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the rxjs operator `switchmap` to achieve your merging behavior. `switchmap` lets you use the result of an Observable but respond with another Observable. So you can chain observables without nested subscriptions like you did (which often causes issues). This would look something like this in your constructor:

```
this.motosWithFavoritesObservable = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  map(user => user.uid),
  switchMap(userid => {
    return this.crudServices.getFavorites(this.basePathU, userid, 'favoritas');
  }),
  switchMap((favorites: { key: string }[]) => {
    return this.crudServices.getMotos(this.basePath).pipe(
      map((motos: { key: string, favourited: boolean }[]) => {
        favorites.forEach(fav => {
          const index = motos.findIndex(moto => moto.key === fav.key)
          if (index !== -1) { // if the moto corresponding to the fav is found in the list
            motos[index].favourited = true;
          }
        })
      })
    )
  })
);

motosWithFavoritesObservable.subscribe(motos => this.motos = motos);
```

Comment: I forgot the `return` in the second switchmap

Comment: did this help you somehow?